# MVVM Light messenger message not received from Command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am building a WPF application using the MVVM Light framework.

I am trying to have a Window open and pass some information, i.e. an object, to this newly created ViewModel.

I have a WPF window (`MainListView`/`MainListViewModel`) which has a `ListBox` bound to a list of objects:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Selected_Agent.Associated_Letter, Mode=OneWay}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_Letter, Mode=TwoWay}">
<!-- More code below -->
```

In `MainListView` I also have a button bound to a command:

```xml
<Button Content="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"/>
```

```cs
private ICommand _updateCommand;
public ICommand UpdateCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_updateCommand == null)
        {
            _updateCommand = new RelayCommand(_windowService.OpenWindow<AddNewLetterView>, UpdateCommand_CanExecute());
            Messenger.Default.Send(new UpdateLetterMessage() { Letter = Selected_Letter });
        }
        return _updateCommand;
    }
}
```

This opens a new window, `AddNewLetterView` using the `AddViewLetterViewModel`, which is linked by MVVM Light's `ViewModelLocator`.

In `AddNewLetterViewModel` constructor I do this:

```cs
public AddNewLetterViewModel()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<UpdateLetterMessage>(this, UpdateLetterMessageReceived);
}
```

The issue is that this message doesn't get received. The breakpoint on `UpdateLetterMessageReceived` is never hit, even though the view opens.

If I put a breakpoint on my command it is never hit, and neither is `UpdateLetterMessageReceived` on the `AddNewLetterViewMdoel`, when the button is clicked, even though the `AddNewLetterView` is opened.

What seems to be happening is that UpdateCommand is called once during MainListViewModel instantiation meaning that the Messenge is sent before `AddNewLetterViewModel` is instantiated.

Is that correct? If so, how can I make sure that my message is sent when the Command is called?

If not, what is going on here and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update command needs to be like this:

```
    private ICommand _updateCommand;

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_updateCommand == null)
            {
                _updateCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    _windowService.OpenWindow<AddNewLetterView> ();
                    Messenger.Default.Send(new UpdateLetterMessage() {Letter = Selected_Letter});
                }, UpdateCommand_CanExecute);
            }
            return _updateCommand;
        }
    }
```

The way you had it, it was only sending the message when the command was first created, where I believe you want to send it when the command is executed

By the way I find this structure for commands more helpful.  Makes it look like a normal method

```
public ICommand UpdateCommand => _updateCommand ?? (_updateCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    _windowService.OpenWindow<AddNewLetterView> 
    Messenger.Default.Send(new UpdateLetterMessage() {Letter = Selected_Letter});
}, UpdateCommand_CanExecute));
```

To make this clearer, your function was doing this:

```
    private ICommand _updateCommand;

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_updateCommand == null)
            {
                _updateCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSomething, CanDoSomething);
                Messenger.Default.Send(etc); <=====THIS SHOULD BE....
            }
            return _updateCommand;
        }
    }

public void DoSomething()
{
    _windowService etc
    <=====.....HERE
}

public bool CanDoSomething() {}
```

The () => {} notation I've used is a shorthand for defining the function DoSomething

Comment: Thank you Tim, that's working exactly as I needed. I don't quite understand what the difference is though, to be honest. What is different about doing `_updateCommand = new RelayCommand();` and `_updateCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { });` in terms of firing on instantiation/execution?

Comment: What you pass into the first parameter of the RelayCommand is the code that is executed when the command is executed.  () => {}  allows you to define many lines of code, not just a single function

Comment: You messenger.send call is called when you create the command, not when the command is executed.

Comment: Ah, amazing! That's made it really clear. I piece I was missing was that `DoSomething` parameter of the RelayCommand. Sometimes the shorthand versions can make it harder to understand what's actually going on and what is being called and when. Thank you for the help.